# Cambiar el color aleatoriamente por cada columna en un Chart c#

Tags: c#

Buen día, tengo un programa que me permite gráficar conectando a una base de datos. Pero, me gustaría que se cambiara de color de manera automática por cada columna, ya que solo me permite mantener un color (azul)en el área de gráfica.

Este es el método que me permite generar mis gráficas.

protected void ObtenerDatos(string strmes)

```
    {

        DataSet resultado = new DataSet();            

        clsConexioncs conexion_server = new clsConexioncs();

        conexion_server.Conexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultDW"].ToString();           


        //conexion_server.PreparaComandoSP("sp_telemtria_femsa");
        conexion_server.PreparaComandoSP("sp_femsa_telemetria_mensual");

        conexion_server.AgregarParametro("Mes", SqlDbType.VarChar, strmes);


        resultado = conexion_server.EjecutaComandoDataSet();


        Graficas_Semanal.Titles.Add("No. Camiones Promedio Mes Actual");
        Graficas_Semanal.ChartAreas["ChartArea"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        Graficas_Semanal.ChartAreas["ChartArea"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;




        Grafica_Dona.Titles.Add("Mes Actual");


        /*
        Graficas_Semanal.Series["Series"].Points.AddXY("Mongue", 125);*/

        foreach (DataRow row in resultado.Tables[0].Rows)
        {



            Graficas_Semanal.Series["Series"].Points.AddXY(row["CeEmplazamiento"], row["Totales"]);

            Grafica_Dona.Series["Series_Dona"].Points.AddXY(row["CeEmplazamiento"], row["Totales"]);

        }

        //Graficas_Semanal.Series["Series"].Points.DataBindXY(resultado.Tables[0],RowNotInTableException[);
        //Graficas_Semanal.Series["Series"].Points.AddXY(nombs, barras);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para darle color a una columna específica podemos hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
miGrafica.Series[miSerie].Points[numColumna].Color = Color.Black;
```

Por ejemplo, si quieres darle color rojo a la primera columna de la serie `Series` de tu gráfica `Grafica_Semanal1` sería:

```
Graficas_Semanal.Series["Series"].Points[0].Color = Color.Red;
```

Como es un vector de puntos, el primer punto es el 0, tú puedes elegir a cuál darle el color.

Si lo que quieres es darle el color al añadir el punto a la gráfica puedes hacer uso de la propiedad `Count` del vector de puntos:

```
Graficas_Semanal.Series["Series"].Points.Count;
```

Eso te dará el número de puntos que tienes en tu gráfica, solo recuerda restarle uno al momento de usarlo.

Si quieres que el color sea aleatorio puedes hacer uso de `Random` para generar un valor aleatorio entre 0 y 255, y pasárselo como parámetro a la función.

```
Color.FromArgb(r,g,b);
```

Entonces el `foreach` quedaria asi:

```
//Añadimos una variable de tipo Random para generar el color aleatorio.
Random r = new Random();

foreach (DataRow row in resultado.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    Graficas_Semanal.Series["Series"].Points.AddXY(row["CeEmplazamiento"],row["Totales"]);
    Grafica_Dona.Series["Series_Dona"].Points.AddXY(row["CeEmplazamiento"],row["Totales"]);
    //Calcula la cantidad de puntos añadido y al último añadido darle el color
    //Graficas_Semanal.Series["Series"].Points.Count-1

    //Asigna el color al último punto añadido a la serie "Series"
    // de la gráfica Graficas_Semanal
    Graficas_Semanal
        .Series["Series"]
        .Points[Graficas_Semanal
        .Series["Series"].Points.Count-1]
        .Color = Color.FromArgb(r.Next(0, 255), r.Next(0, 255), r.Next(0, 255));

    //Asigna el color al último punto añadido a la serie "Series"
    // de la grafica Graficas_Semanal
    Grafica_Dona
       .Series["Series_Dona"]
       .Points[Grafica_Dona
       .Series["Series"]
       .Points.Count]
       .Color = Color.FromArgb(r.Next(0, 255), r.Next(0, 255), r.Next(0, 255));
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: no funciona cuando cargo el chart mediante datasource...